# Pointer to array of pointers points to unexpected address

Tags: c, pointers, struct

The question is related to my former question here:
[Arduino compile error while using reference to a struct in another struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397551/arduino-compile-error-while-using-reference-to-a-struct-in-another-struct)

I ported the sample code back to the pc and compiled it  to get a clue, what's going wrong.

Here's the sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int steps=64;
unsigned int mode=0;
unsigned int speed=1;


typedef struct{
  unsigned int option_value;
  char option_name[17];
} SELECTION;

typedef struct{
  char item_name[17];
  unsigned int* variable;
  SELECTION** options;
} MENU_ITEM;


SELECTION mode_forward = { 0, "Forward" };
SELECTION mode_backward = { 1, "Backward" };
SELECTION* options_mode[] = { &mode_forward, &mode_backward };

SELECTION speed_slow = { 0, "Slow" };
SELECTION speed_normal = { 1, "Normal" };
SELECTION speed_fast = { 2, "Fast" };
SELECTION* options_speed[] = { &speed_slow, &speed_normal, &speed_fast };

MENU_ITEM menu_steps = { "Steps", &steps, NULL }; 
MENU_ITEM menu_mode = { "Mode", &mode, options_mode }; 
MENU_ITEM menu_speed = { "Speed", &speed, options_speed }; 
MENU_ITEM menu_exit = { "Exit", NULL, NULL }; 

const unsigned char menu_items = 4;
MENU_ITEM* menu_list[menu_items] = { &menu_steps, &menu_mode, &menu_speed, &menu_exit };
//-----------------------------------------------------------

int main(){

  int options;

  options=(int)(sizeof(options_speed)/sizeof(options_speed[0]));
  printf("Speed options: %i\n\n",options);

  printf("Address of speed_slow:  %p\n",&speed_slow);
  printf("Address of speed_normal:  %p\n",&speed_normal);
  printf("Address of speed_fast:  %p\n",&speed_fast);
  printf("Address of array:  %p\n\n",&options_speed);

  MENU_ITEM item;
  item=*menu_list[2];

  printf("Menu Item: %s - Item Value: %i\n",item.item_name,*item.variable);
  printf("Address of name: %p\n",&item.item_name);
  printf("Address of variable-pointer: %p\n",&item.variable);
  printf("Address of options-pointer: %p\n",&item.options);
  printf("Value of options-pointer: %p\n",*item.options);


  return 0;
}
```

When i start the program i get the following output:

```
Speed options: 3

Address of speed_slow:  0x6010c0
Address of speed_normal:  0x6010e0
Address of speed_fast:  0x601100
Address of array:  0x601120

Menu Item: Speed - Item Value: 1
Address of name: 0x7fff18a5dc90
Address of variable-pointer: 0x7fff18a5dca8
Address of options-pointer: 0x7fff18a5dcb0
Value of options-pointer: 0x6010c0
```

That's what i expect....except the last line. Shouldn't the address that it points to be `0x601120` - the address of `options_speed` array? 
Why does it point to the first member of the array instead?
What do i have to change to let it point to `0x601120`?

Comment: Verify the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) of `*menu_list[2]` is doing what you think it is.

Comment: `*menu_list[2]` and `*(menu_list[2])` give me the same result, so i assume that part to be right...but i'll add the parentheseis, just to be sure.

Comment: It would definitely clarify intent, though you're correct, I believe. I also think 6502 is accurate in his answer.  [see it live](http://ideone.com/wSgwJ7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are evaluating `*item.options`, not `item.options`. This seems is not what you wanted to print (i.e. the "options pointer") as there is an extra dereferencing operation.

Comment: Yeah...it's a step forward. If a change the line from 
`printf("Value of options-pointer: %p\n",*item.options);`
to
`printf("Value of options-pointer: %p\n",item.options);`
i'm getting the right result....but now i stuck on the next step.

I'll play around a bit, before coming back to that question.